# Clang apresenta erro character too large mas Visual Studio compila normal

Tags: c, c++, string, visual-studio, clang

Estou com dificuldades de entender porque o clang apresenta a mensagem de erro

> character too large for enclosing character literal type

ao tentar executar o código:

```
char c = 'ç';
```

enquanto o Visual Studio 2015 compila sem problemas. Eu sei que diferentes compiladores podem e tem suas implementações diferentes. E que ç está fora da tabela ASCII, que o valor numérico deve ser maior que 127 por isso do Clang informar que não é possível armazenar dentro da tipo `char`. Mas ainda gostaria de saber:

Por que o Clang não permite que eu utilize 'ç' como um char enquanto o Visual Studio permite? É alguma coisa pré-definida no Visual Studio? Alguma opção baseado na linguagem do meu sistema?

Porque o Visual Studio retorna o valor "correto" nas funções de `string`, como `strlen` mesmo passando strings com acentos?

Exemplo: `strlen("opção");` Retorna 5 no Visual Studio, eu esperava o retorno ser 7 como o Clang retorna.

Comment: Arriscaria dizer que por este caracter não pertencer ao padrão ASCII ele ocupa mais que 1 byte (enquanto o tipo `char` só suporta este tamanho). Veja se há como setar alguma opção para considerar o código fonte como UTF-8 na hora de executar.

Comment: Sim, acredito seja isso no clang, lá o strlen volta o valor em bytes, ou seja mais de 1 byte para ç. Pelo que vi o gcc permite alterar o encoding, porém o clang não tem tal opção. Mas o que me intriga o fato do Visual Studio simplesmente funcionar sem nenhum tipo de aviso para caracteres fora da tabela ascii. Mesmo usando ascii estendido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro: compilar ou funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Todo programador deve ter isso muito claramente. Fez bem em perguntar aqui para entender porque funciona ou não.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Eu não tenho uma informação oficial (achei algumas informações soltas que indicam isso), mas posso inferir que o compilador C da Microsoft, que por acaso é usado por padrão no Visual Studio, está usando uma codificação de caracteres de apenas um byte, possivelmente Windows 1252. Esta usa uma tabela estendida do ASCII (que só tem 127 caracteres) permitindo alguns caracteres acentuados. Não funcionará com caracteres que estejam fora desta pequena tabela de 255 caracteres.

Recentemente [o novo compilador permitiu controlar melhor como tratar isso](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Está claro pra mim que o Clang usa UTF-8 por padrão (até li em alguns lugares não oficiais que é isso mesmo), que é uma codificação multi-byte. Quando usa caracteres além da tabela ASCII ele precisa ser representado por 2 ou mais bytes.

Isso explica porque o `char` não funciona, afinal a especificação do C diz claramente que este tipo deve ter 1 byte sempre.

A função `strlen()` retorna o valor correto, afinal ela se propõe retornar a quantidade de bytes e não de caracteres.

Ainda aconselho procurar na documentação para confirmar se são essas codificações padrões mesmo.

Use [`wchar_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) para garantir um tipo multi-byte. Ou [`wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) em C++.

Leia sobre as [funções de *string* multi-byte do C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte).

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e realmente parece ser o caso, existe uma falta de documentação sobre essa discrepância. Mas bem ao tentar utilizar um carácter de outra linguagem o VisualC me deu a mensagem:  ```warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u30C8' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)```, outra coisa que percebi que se o arquivo estiver com a codificação 1252 o visual studio substitui os caracteres fora dessa code page para um ?(char code 63) em vez de causar erro.. o que faz o código compilar, mas não funciona de forma correta.

Comment: Ou Unicode literals em vez de wide chars: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @pepper_chico em C++, sim, claro.