# Um tipo "char" sempre tem tamanho 1 mesmo?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, tipagem, char

Sempre soube que um `char` é o único tipo que tem tamanho fixo pela especificação. Seu tamanho é 1, não importa a arquitetura.

Mas me deparei com `sizeof('a')` retornando 4 e não 1.

Como isso? Aprendi errado?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você aprendeu pela metade. De fato quando pede o `sizeof` de uma variável to tipo `char`, ou o próprio tipo `char`, o resultado sempre será 1. Nunca mudará, então não existe razão para usar uma expressão para pegar seu tamanho. Use o literal 1 e pronto.

Pode dizer "por via das dúvidas", "por desencardo de consciência", "vai que um dia mude". Não vai mudar, especificação de linguagem não pode mudar porque alguém quis. Programação não pode ser baseada em crenças. Tem o certo e o errado. No máximo, estilo pode ter gosto. Se gosta de usar `sizeof(char)` só posso lamentar, porque é gosto. Mas achar que pode não ser 1 é sandice.

De fato se fizer um `sizeof` de um literal caractere vai resultar no tamanho de um `int`. Pra mim foi um erro da linguagem especificar isso e não vejo utilidade. Nem use essa forma, não tem necessidade, use 1.

É tão conceitualmente errado que C++ achou melhor tornar isso incompatível e a linguagem resulta em 1 mesmo.

Em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof('a'));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/wpiyD2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rzgixwpb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/SizeofChar.c).

Em C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    cout << sizeof(char) << "\n";
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
    cout << sizeof('a')  << "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/lyleAY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xdjvokxt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/SizeofChar.cpp).

Comment: Uma pergunta, e se for um caracter especial, não ascii? por exemplo "â", terá na mesma 1 byte? Porque `sizeof(a)` tem um tamanho diferente de `sizeof('a')` em C?

Comment: @Miguel Isso já é outra questão, mas vamos lá: `char` só tem 1 byte, não importa a codificação, ASCII, Latin1, etc. Se usar alguma codificação multi-byte nele é um erro, na verdade cada byte desse suposto caractere do ponto de vista do `char` será um erro. Claro que nada impede de você ter funções que interpretem isso corretamente, mas é fora do padrão, o que existe em C e que terceiros provavelmente farão, não funciona. Se precisa de multi-byte, é outro tipo. A segunda parte, acho que está na resposta, não? É por especificação que o literal é diferente e que considero um erro.

Comment: Percebido, bigown posso fazer a pergunta porque acho que muitos como eu terão essa duvida "e se for um caracter especial, não ascii?" , vindo de PHP e conhecendo tantos "problemas" que advêm disso, ex: `strpos` vs `mb_strpos`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913411/mb-strpos-vs-strpos-whats-the-difference

Comment: @Miguel fique à vontade. Nunca precisa pedir permissão pra perguntar :)

Comment: Caracteres especiais em codificações multi-byte simplesmetne não cabem em um tipo char em "c" - simples assim.  
Se você tentar fazer char = 'ã';  e o seu arquivo estiver codificado em utf-8, por exemplo, você deve te rum erro na compilação.  

O que se precisa ter em mente - e que o bigown naõ explicitou até aqui é que: **é errado achar que um byte corresponde a um caractére** . 
Leiam http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Comment: @jsbueno isso, conforme eu já havia respondido em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137047/101.