# format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ - O que é isso? Como arrumar?

Tags: c, ponteiro, printf

#### Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        char caractere, *caractere_ptr = &caractere;

        printf("Caractere: foi alocado %zu byte\n", sizeof(caractere));
        printf("Endereço: %d", caractere_ptr);

        return 0;
}
```

#### Erro que está sendo exibido:

> ```
> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
>   printf("Endereço: %d", caractere_ptr);
> ```

O que gostaria que fosse exibido é o **endereço de memória** da variável, e não o seu valor. Por esse motivo, eu não a inicializei.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para imprimir o endereço da memória deve usar o `%p`. Desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char caractere, *caractere_ptr = &caractere;
    printf("Caractere: foi alocado %zu byte\n", sizeof(caractere));
    printf("Endereço: %p", caractere_ptr);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/grDMea). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rjryovex-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Printf.c).

Vou manter a resposta original abaixo para referência porque ela ainda é útil para algumas pessoas, mas ela não é o que o autor da pergunta desejava, e o que foi dito parte de um pressuposto que agora se mostra errado.

---

Mas se quiser fazer funcionar corretamente deve usar `%s`.

Há uma [tabela de códigos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) que podem ser usados em uma *string* de formatação do `printf()`.

Nesse caso você tem um ponteiro para caractere (`char *`) para um caractere, portanto é um *string* que você quer imprimir, então o correto é `%s`. Se fosse o caractere aí seria `%c`. Com sorte ele não imprimirá nada, mas pode imprimir muita coisa indesejada porque quando manda imprimir uma *string* ele só para quando encontra um caractere nulo `\0`, e pode ter muita sujeira até achar um nulo. Falo disto em [Qual a diferença entre "NULL", "\0" e 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101)

Note que o que vai imprimir é um lixo, já que a variável `caractere` não foi inicializada.

Comment: Eu só quero imprimir o endereço de memória... Se endereços de memórias são números inteiros, não seria adequado utilizar %d? Por que %s?

Comment: @Dracalbus está tudo na tabela que eu *linkei*. Editei a resposta para mostrar o que deseja de fato.

Comment: Pois é, o cara do CProgressivo mostrou que para imprimir os endereços de memória, seria necessário %d...

Comment: @Dracalbus não sei o que é esse CProgressivo, mas não é o normal. Eu sei que tem compilador que aceita, mas é fora de padrão, então é melhor aprender pelo certo. Programar não é ver funcionando, é fazer o certo. Toda literatura de qualidade de C fala claramente que ponteiros devem ser impressos com `%p`.

Comment: Eu não a inicializei, porque eu não pretendia exibir seu valor, mas sim seu endereço.

Comment: @Dracalbus aí faz algum sentido mesmo, pelo menos em uma experimentação.

Comment: @Dracalbus isso pode te interessar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/101

Answer (score 7):

O `%d` é para a impressão de números inteiros.

Para imprimir caracteres utilize o `%c`

Como dito no comentário que a intenção é imprimir o valor inteiro do endereço de memória de `*caractere_ptr`.

Como dito pela resposta do Maniero, o correto é utilizar o `%p`

Aqui deixo alguns parâmetros de impressão que retirei [daqui](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_simples).

```
Código  Conversão/Formato do argumento
%d  Número decimal inteiro (int). Também pode ser usado %i como equivalente a %d.
%u  Número decimal natural (unsigned int), ou seja, sem sinal.
%o  Número inteiro representado na base octal. Exemplo: 41367 (corresponde ao decimal 17143).
%x  Número inteiro representado na base hexadecimal. Exemplo: 42f7 (corresponde ao decimal 17143). Se usarmos %X, as letras serão maiúsculas: 42F7.
%X  Hexadecimal com letras maiúsculas
%f  Número decimal de ponto flutuante. No caso da função printf, devido às conversões implícitas da linguagem C, serve tanto para float como para double. No caso da função scanf, %f serve para float e %lf serve para double.
%e  Número em notação científica, por exemplo 5.97e-12. Podemos usar %E para exibir o E maiúsculo (5.97E-12).
%E  Número em notação científica com o "e"maiúsculo
%g  Escolhe automaticamente o mais apropriado entre %f e %e. Novamente, podemos usar %G para escolher entre %f e %E.
%p  Ponteiro: exibe o endereço de memória do ponteiro em notação hexadecimal.
%c  Caractere: imprime o caractere que tem o código ASCII correspondente ao valor dado.
%s  Sequência de caracteres (string, em inglês).
%%  Imprime um %
```

Comment: Mas é justamente isso que quero fazer, imprimir um número inteiro, que no caso é o endereço de memória...

Comment: Entendi, poderia ter deixado explícito na pergunta. Pode editá-la agora e colocar sua dúvida? Vou editar aqui e colocar a resposta para esta, de movo que fique consistente a quem venha parar aqui no futuro.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, a fim tornar mais fácil para aqueles que estiverem com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 6):

`%d` é para mostrar `inteiros`

Se você quer mostrar `char`, você deveria utilizar `%s`

Comment: Não quero mostrar char, quero mostrar um inteiro, que é o endereço de memória da variável.