# Problema com armazenamento e impressão de strings em C

Tags: c, string

Estou pegando palavras de um arquivo de texto, e na hora de imprimir elas está tudo certo, exceto quando armazeno elas num vetor. Se eu armazeno-as num vetor, na hora de imprimir, antes das palavras saem alguns caracteres aleatórios.

```
void leArquivo(FILE* f, int numPalavras){
char palavra[30];
int flag = 0, i = 0, terminou = 0, cont = 0;
char** vetorDesord = malloc(sizeof(char)*(numPalavras-1));
    while(!terminou){
    flag = fscanf(f, "%s", palavra);
    if (flag != EOF){
         removeChar(palavra, '.', ',', ' ', ';', '"');
         palavra[0] = tolower(palavra[0]);
         vetorDesord[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(palavra));
         vetorDesord[i] = palavra;
        printf("%s", palavra);
        i++;
    }
    else terminou = 1;
    cont++;
}
```

Já testei:

1. Sem armazenar no vetor, imprime tudo correto.
2. Sem as funções `tolower()` e `removeChar()`, o erro continua o mesmo
3. Armazenando no vetor, qualquer coisa que eu imprimir nesse trecho (ex: `printf("a")`) também imprime com erro
4. Usei `strcpy()`, o erro persistiu

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários erros e a solução é mais complexa do que precisa e bastante ineficiente, além de fugir do padrão que se costuma fazer em C.

Geralmente alocamos a memória necessária onde precisa e passamos para a função manipular. Evitamos bastante usar `malloc()`, principalmente porque as pessoas esquecem de dar `free()`, o que parece ser o caso. Mesmo que não queira passar o vetor já alocado, parece que poderia alocar na sua função mesmo.

Eu não faria isso porque a função está lendo e imprimindo dados, são coisas distintas, isso geralmente é considerado errado.

Eu não escrevi a função que remove caracteres, espero que ela esteja simples e correta, mas tenho certeza que não. E é lá que já deve tornar as letras minúsculas, além de ser mais eficiente é o correto, o que está fazendo no seu código é usar uma função que converte uma caractere para tentar fazer na palavra toda, não dá certo, no máximo fará no primeiro caractere da palavra.

Seu código dá problema se tiver mais palavras que o que você espera. O controle do laço está complexo demais. E tem variáveis demais. Tem outras melhorias a serem feitas.

E se for usar o `malloc()` mesmo, [não faz sentido usar `sizeof(char)` porque ele sempre é 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/101). E [usar `strlen()` quase sempre é erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101). E aí [teria que usar `strcpy()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136628/101), o que é mais uma ineficiência.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int leDados(FILE* arquivo, int numPalavras, char palavras[numPalavras][31]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPalavras; i++) {
        if (fscanf(arquivo, "%30s", palavras[i]) == EOF) return i;
        //removeCharETornaMinuscula(palavra, '.', ',', ' ', ';', '"');
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char palavras[10][31];
    int numPalavras = leDados(stdin, 10, palavras);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPalavras; i++) printf("%s\n", palavras[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DravFr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pwnwazmf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/HandlingFromFile.c).