# Como criar uma função que conte os caracteres de um frase e mostre a frequência de um?

Tags: c

#### Contexto

Preciso criar uma função - utilizando a linguagem C - que a partir de uma frase conte seus caracteres e informe quantas vezes cada carácter apareceu.

#### Exemplo

**Frase**: boa prova a todos
**Resultado**:

```
b = 1
o = 4
a = 3
p = 1
r = 1
v = 1
t = 1
d = 1
s = 1
! = 1
```

Comment: Uma possibilidade é você ordenar os caracteres de sua string e ir contando as repetições. Não vi em sua tabela o contador de espaços, não é para contar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiz o algoritmo de acordo com a idéia do @anonimo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* frase;
    fgets (frase, 256, stdin);

    // Verificando se o último caracter é uma quebra de linha e substituindo
    if (frase[strlen(frase)-1] == '\n') {
        frase[strlen(frase)-1] = '\0';
    }

    // Ordenando a frase
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < strlen(frase); o++) {
            if (frase[i] < frase[o]) {
                char temp = frase[i];
                frase[i] = frase[o];
                frase[o] = temp;
            }
        }    
    }

    // Imprimindo na tela    
    char caracterAtual = frase[1];
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(frase); i++) {
        if (frase[i] != ' ') {
            if (frase[i] == caracterAtual) {
                contador++;
            } else {
                if (caracterAtual != ' ') {
                    printf("%c = %d\n", caracterAtual, contador);
                }
                contador = 1;
                caracterAtual = frase[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Primeiramente ele ordena os caracteres da frase pros iguais ficarem um ao lado do outro.
Segundamente, ele percorre a string ordenada e vai contando quantos caracteres iguais são seguidos um do outro, se o próximo caracter for diferente, ele imprime a quantidade que achou e recomeça o contador. Nesse exemplo que fiz ele vai ignorar os espaços. Lógico que dá pra melhorar mas C não é minha especialidade.

---

Entrada:

```
boa prova a todos!
```

Saída:

```
! = 1
a = 3
b = 1
d = 1
o = 4
p = 1
r = 1
s = 1
t = 1
v = 1
```

Comment: Apenas uma observação: a função `fgets` incorpora, como um caractere da string lida o caractere `\n` que sinaliza o final da entrada (desde que a string lida tenha menos caracteres que o máximo especificado na função), assim você deve verificar se o último caractere da string é o '\n' e, se for, substitui-lo por um '\0'.

Comment: Obrigado pelo alerta. Editei a resposta, poderia dizer se o que fiz está correto?

Comment: Tem um problema - que muitas vezes não é percebido - que é ficar chamando `strlen` várias vezes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/112052

Comment: Sem contar que chamar `fgets` sem antes ter alocado memória para a frase gera comportamento indefinido e não é garantido que funcione sempre - exemplo: https://ideone.com/6PkLjg

Comment: [Não use a função `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167528/sempre-que-vou-varrer-um-string-em-c-devo-usar-o-strlen-certo) para iterar por uma string, facilita a leitura mas pesa na performance do código

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do que fez a outra resposta, não precisa ordenar caracteres nem nada disso.

Basta percorrer os caracteres e ir computando os totais. E como [um `char` em C sempre tem 1 byte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/112052) (e portanto há 256 valores possíveis), você pode criar um array com 256 posições, e ir guardando os totais de cada caractere nele:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = malloc(1024);
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao alocar memória\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("digite a frase:");
    if (fgets(str, 1024, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao ler dados\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int counts[256] = { 0 };
    // percorre a string, atualizando a contagem de cada caractere
    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0' && *ptr != '\n'; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr != ' ') // entendi que não conta os espaços
            counts[(unsigned char) *ptr]++;
    }

    // mostra os totais que forem maiores que zero
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (counts[i] != 0)
            printf("%c = %d\n", i, counts[i]);
    }

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Não esqueça também de alocar espaço para a string antes de chamar `fgets` - a outra resposta não fez isso, e se funcionou, é por coincidência, pois chamar `fgets` sem alocar memória antes tem [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/112052) e não é garantido que funcione sempre - tanto que eu testei sem alocar memória e não funcionou (veja a diferença [aqui](https://ideone.com/6PkLjg) e [aqui](https://ideone.com/B2PjFU)).

Enfim, eu fiz um `for` verificando se o caractere não é o *null terminator* ou o `\n` - pois `fgets` adiciona o `\n`, exceto se você digitar mais caracteres que o indicado pelo segundo parâmetro (pois neste caso não terá o `\n`).

Claro que se for usar esta string depois e não quiser o `\n`, aí vale a pena fazer o que foi feito na outra resposta. Mas se só quer contar os caracteres e nada mais, acho mais simples fazer um único *loop* e parar quando encontrar o `\n` ou o `\0`.

Neste *loop* vou atualizando a contagem de cada caractere, aproveitando o fato de que na verdade `char` são bytes e podem ser interpretados como números (e portanto, posso usá-los como índices do array `counts`). Eu não contei os espaços, que parece ser o que você queria (mas se for o caso, é só mudar o `if` dentro do `for`, para escolher quais caracteres serão contados).

Isso é mais eficiente por percorrer a string apenas uma única vez. Não vi necessidade nenhuma de ordená-la (e ainda mais usando um algoritmo quadrático), e ainda por cima `strlen` é chamado várias vezes, [o que torna tudo mais ineficiente ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/112052).