# Erro ao ler um arquivo e salva-lo em em espaço alocado dinamicamente em c

Tags: c, arquivo, alocação

Eu quero criar um programa que:

1. Abre o arquivo `teste`
2. Descobri o tamanho deste arquivo
3. Aloca na memoria o espaço suficiente para o arquivo + 1 (`\0`)
4. Leia o conteudo do arquivo usando a função `fread` e salva no local alocado
5. Imprime o conteudo lido

Porém quando executo o programa ele imprime um monte de caracteres aleatorios como se estivesse convertendo um numero aleatorio em  ascii-code

Eu sei que `fread()` nao e o jeito mais eficiente, mais e apenas um teste para um problema real em um codigo fonte maior e que eu deduzi que o problema seria uma parte parecida

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int FileSize;
    int result;
    char *c;
    
    file = fopen("P:\\teste", "r");
    
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    FileSize = ftell(file);
    
    c = (char *) malloc((FileSize+1) * sizeof(char));
    
    result = fread(c, sizeof(char), FileSize, file);
    printf("%s", c);
    
    free(c);
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` seta a posição para o final do arquivo. Então o `fread` começa a ler daí, mas como ele já está no final do arquivo, não há mais o que ler.

Por isso você precisa voltar ao início do arquivo antes de ler. E também tem que lembrar de adicionar o terminador no final da string:

```c
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // volta para o início do arquivo
fread(c, 1, FileSize, file); // lê tudo
c[FileSize] = '\0'; // adiciona o terminador
```

Lembrando que [`sizeof(char)` sempre é 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/112052), então pode usar `1` direto, sem medo.

---

Outro detalhe é que [não precisa fazer *cast* no `malloc`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285420/112052), então poderia ser apenas:

```
c = malloc(FileSize + 1);
```

E na verdade, não precisa declarar todas as variáveis no início para só depois usá-las no decorrer do programa (isso já foi verdade no passado, mas sei lá porque tem gente que ainda usa - e alguns até ensinam - assim). Você pode declarar uma variável no momento em que é usada. Ou seja:

```c
FILE *file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int FileSize = ftell(file);
char *c = malloc(FileSize + 1);

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(c, 1, FileSize, file);
c[FileSize] = '\0';
```

Vale lembrar também que em um código mais sério você deveria verificar o retorno de todas as funções: `fread` retorna a quantidade que foi lida, então você pode comparar com `FileSize` para saber se tudo foi lido com sucesso; `ftell` retorna `-1L` (o "L" indica que é um `long`) em caso de erro, `fopen` retorna um ponteiro nulo se ocorrer algum erro ao abrir o arquivo, etc.