# Qual a maneira correta para alocar memoria dinamicamente para um ponteiro de char dentro de um array de struct em Programação C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, programação-estruturada, falha-de-segmentação

Gostaria de saber qual é a maneira correta de alocar memoria dinamicamente para uma string dentro de um array de structs em programação C.

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
} NAME;

...

NAME **nome;

nome = (NAME **)malloc(5*sizeof(NAME *));

...

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  /* Aqui tenho o erro de Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada) */
  nome[i]->name = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

};
```

As verificações de ponteiro NULL estão no código, simplifiquei com minha dúvida em específico. Nesse exemplo quero alocar dinamicamente 05 structs, cada uma com string de 9 char mais o caractere de final '\0'.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Acho que seria apenas `NAME *nome = malloc(5 * sizeof *nome);` e `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { nome[i].name = malloc(10); }` (não precisa ser ponteiro de ponteiro, acho uma complicação desnecessária). Repare também que [não precisa fazer *cast* do `malloc`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/112052), e `sizeof(char)` [sempre é 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/112052), e portanto redundante e desnecessário.

Answer (score 0):

Declaramos a struct:

```
typedef struct {    
    double var; // acrescentei apenas para uma observação ao final
    char* name;
} Name;
```

Declara-se um array de 5 ponteiros cada um do tipo `Name*`.

```
Name* (names[5]);
```

É feito um loop varrendo os 5 ponteiros. Para cada um deve ser alocada memória dinamicamente, considerando que apontam para uma struct `Name`. Na sequência, para cada struct deve ser alocada memória dinamicamente para `name`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                
    names[i] = malloc(sizeof(Name));
    names[i]->name = malloc(9*sizeof(char) + 1);
}
```

São escritos os nomes:

```
strcpy(names[0]->name, "Pedro I");
strcpy(names[1]->name, "Pedro II");
strcpy(names[2]->name, "Maria I");
strcpy(names[3]->name, "Maria II");
strcpy(names[4]->name, "Maria II");
```

Desaloca-se a memória:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    free(names[i]->name);
    free(names[i]);
}
```

Código para referência: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9xv6b1c8x)

---

**Observação**

Na linha:

```
names[i] = malloc(sizeof(Name));
```

`sizeof(Name)` será `sizeof(double)` + `sizeof(char*)`. `sizeof(double)`é o tamanho de um `double`, enquanto `sizeof(char*)` é o tamanho do ponteiro, o que  é diferente de `sizeof(char)`. Em uma máquina de 64 bits `sizeof(char*)` geralmente é 8 bytes, assim como `sizeof(int*)`, `sizeof(double*)`, etc... [Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four).