# Como fazer meu código ser lido em UTF-8 em C?

Tags: c

Quando eu rodo esse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int teste[10];
  printf("Imprimindo o vetor 'teste': %d\n", teste);
  printf("O endereço do primeiro elemento é: %d\n", teste[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

As letras "é" e a "ç" saem com esses símbolos estranhos:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer com que essas letras sejam lidas pelo programa com a codificação em UTF-8?

Comment: Acho que isto responde, não? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137043/101

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Clang apresenta erro character too large mas Visual Studio compila normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137043/clang-apresenta-erro-character-too-large-mas-visual-studio-compila-normal)

Comment: Falta o `setlocale (LC_ALL, "portuguese");` e respetiva configuração do IDE

Comment: Discordo disso ser duplicata. A outra pergunta é sobre problemas de compilação devido ao fato de alguns caracteres terem mais de um byte. Nesta dequi, o fato de um caractere ser ou não representado em um byte tem pouca importância. Além disso, não consigo enxergar como a resposta do @Maniero de lá possa resolver o problema daqui, ela apenas explica um pouco mais acerca de problemas de encoding que aqui existem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode colocar o código ASCII direto no printf ou vc pode adicionar a biblioteca locale.h e adicionar a linha setlocale (LC_ALL, ""); no inicio do código